# Install Azure CLI on VM using Chef

Tags: linux, azure, chef-infra, yum, recipe

I am currently writing a script(recipe) with Chef that executes on an Azure (Linux) virtual machine. For my purposes I need to install Azure CLI on that VM. I followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest) from the documentation. Unfortunately, I get the error that I can't use "sudo", and if I remove "sudo" it can't find "azure-cli". That part of the recipe looks like this:

```
cli = 'echo -e "[azure-cli] \ nname = Azure CLI \ nbaseurl = https: //packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli \ nenabled = 1 \ ngpgcheck = 1 \ ngpgkey = https: //packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc "> /etc/yum.repos.d/azure-cli.repo ' 

execute "Install Azure CLI 1" do
    command "sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.co/keys/microsoft.asc"
end

execute "Install Azure CLI 2" do
    command "sudo sh -c " + cli
end

execute "Install Azure CLI 3" do
    command "yes | sudo yum install azure-cli"
end
```

How can I make it work? Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically Chef'ified a Shell script. IMO that is **not** the ideal way. Take some time to familiarize yourself with [Chef Resources](https://docs.chef.io/resources/) to get the job done.

For example:

- To manage the YUM repository - use [yum_repository](https://docs.chef.io/resources/yum_repository/) resource.
- To install package - use the [yum_package](https://docs.chef.io/resources/yum_package) resource.

At the very minimum, something like below:

```rb
yum_repository 'azure-cli' do
  description 'Azure CLI'
  baseurl 'https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli'
  gpgkey 'https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc'
end

yum_package 'azure-cli'
```